# Laravel: Why are results from the database being displayed in the view differently than what Dump&Die says is retrieved?

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have a table called parts. The primary key is part_id, it is not to be incremented, it is a VARCHAR (Laravel string). All part id's are 2 numbers, hyphen, 4 numbers (e.g. **12-3456**)

When the results from a query are displayed in the web browser they are not entirely the same as what Dump&Die `<?php dd($parts); ?>` says is being retrieved...

Here is what I have figured out from adding test parts to the database:

- It seems zeros before a single digit are not displayed.
  (e.g. **04** is displayed as **4**, **44** is displayed as **44**)
- The character `-` is not displayed and nor are any other characters that follow this.
  (e.g. **04-0001** is displayed as **4**, **44-4444** is displayed as **44**)
- An entry with just letters displays as a 0.
  (e.g. **hello** is displayed as **0**, **g** is displayed as **0**)
- A string of only numbers is displayed as is expected.
  (e.g. **1234** is displayed as **1234**, **123456789** is displayed as **123456789**)

Any ideas why this would be? I'm completely stumped...

**Code and screenshots below for clarity.**

[Screenshot from browser with dd() function called.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAOTk.png)

This screenshot shows the result displayed in the browser **1** and the result from the dd() function **01-2222**.

**The Laravel view in question:**

```
@extends ('layouts.default')

@section ('content')

    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="mb-4 pb-2">Inventory</h1>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-9">

                <a href="/states" class="btn btn-uce">States</a>
                

                <div>
                    <p>DEVELOPMENT TASKS</p>
                    <div style="background-color: rgb(207, 70, 70)">
                        <p>- Make each header option have drop down for more options (Sort by etc.)</p>
                        <p>- Add filter options</p>
                        <p>- Total quantity = total of that item in all states</p>
                    </div>
                </div>

                
                <table class="parts-table" style="width:100%">
                    <tr class="parts-column-headers">
                        <th>Part ID</th>
                        <th>Part Name</th>
                        <th>Part Description</th>
                        <th>Total Quantity</th>
                    </tr>

                    @forelse ($parts as $part) 
                        <nav>
                            <tr class="parts-rows">
                                <th><a href="/parts/{{ $part->part_id }}">{{ $part->part_id }}</a></th>
                                <th>{{ $part->part_name }}</th>
                                <th>{{ $part->part_description }}</th>
                                <th>0</th>
                            </tr>
                        </nav>

                    @empty
                    
                        <h1>No Parts Registered Yet!</h1>

                    @endforelse
                </table>

                <?php dd($parts); ?>

                <div>
                    <a href="parts/create" class="btn btn-uce">Create Part</a>
                </div>
                
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
@endsection
```

**My migration for this table:**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreatePartsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('parts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('part_id', 100);
            $table->string('part_name');
            $table->string('part_description');
            $table->timestamps();
            
            $table->primary('part_id');
            $table->unique('part_id');
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('parts');
    }
}
```

**The Controller:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Part;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PartController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        $parts = Part::all();

        return view('parts.index', compact('parts'));
    }



    public function show(Part $part) {
        
        return view('parts.show', compact('part'));
    }


    public function create() {
        return view('parts.create');
    }




    public function store() {

        // validate 
        $attributes = request()->validate([
            'part_id' => 'required',
            'part_name' => 'required',
            'part_description' => 'required'
        ]);

        // persist 
        Part::create($attributes);
        
        // redirect 
        return redirect('/parts');
    }


}
```

**The Model:**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Part extends Model
{
    protected $primaryKey = 'part_id';
    protected $guarded = [];

    
    public function path() {

        return "/parts/{$this->part_id}";
    }
}
```

If any more information is needed to help debug this please ask me to provide it. I'm sure I've missed something silly but I keep looking over the code and can't see it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using the part_id as your primary key.  This is a poor choice, and unneccessary for the sake of one column on the database.

You need to set `public $incrementing=false;` on the model to tell Eloquent not to cast the column as an unsigned integer.

Comment: Thanks @Snapey that worked. Can you elaborate on why part_id is a poor choice of primary key?

Comment: Because you run into problems like this, and you are also relying on its uniqueness.  Now in the case of a part number this might be what you want, but I think you will have more battles with this..  I just don't like arbitrary strings as primary keys

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686346/databases-string-as-primary-key